# Perl - Combine multiple regexps without renumbering?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to combine multiple regexps into one, so code which looks like this:

```
my $s = "jump 0xbdf3487";
#my $s = "move 0xbdf3487";                                                                                         

if ($s =~ m/^(move) ([^ ]+)/) {  print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";  }
if ($s =~ m/^(jump) ([^ ]+)/) {  print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";  }
if ($s =~ m/^(call) ([^ ]+)/) {  print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";  }
```

becomes:

```
my $s = "jump 0xbdf3487";
#my $s = "move 0xbdf3487";                                                                                         

my @patterns = (
    '^(move) ([^ ]+)',
    '^(jump) ([^ ]+)',
    '^(call) ([^ ]+)'
  );

my $re = "(?:" . join("|", @patterns) . ")";
$re = qr/$re/;

if ($s =~ m/$re/) {  print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";  }
```

This doesn't work however, if `$s` is a jump we get:

```
matched '' ''
```

Matches in the combined regexp get renumbered:
($1, $2) become ($3, $4) in the jump regexp, ($5, $6) in the call one etc..

How do I combine these without renumbering ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the branch reset pattern `(?|pattern)` (you'll need Perl 5.10 or newer though). Quoting the documentation ([`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?|pattern))):

> This is the "branch reset" pattern, which has the special property that the capture groups are numbered from the same starting point in each alternation branch.

Your code becomes:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $s = "jump 0xbdf3487";
#my $s = "move 0xbdf3487";                                                                                         

my @patterns = (
    '(move) ([^ ]+)',
    '(jump) ([^ ]+)',
    '(call) ([^ ]+)'
  );

my $re = "^(?|" . join("|", @patterns) . ")";
$re = qr/$re/;
if ($s =~ m/$re/) {  print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";  }
```

*Note that I've added `use strict` and `use warnings`, don't forget them!*

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple alternation in your regex and use just a single regex:

```
m/^(move|jump|call) ([^ ]+)/
```

**Code:**

```
my $s = "jump 0xbdf3487";

if ($s =~ m/^(move|jump|call) ([^ ]+)/) {
   print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";
}
```

Comment: On this simple example this makes complete sense. Actually the situation i'm dealing with has many more regexps, and each one is pretty complicated so combining them all on a single line would look pretty dreadful ...

Comment: @lemonsqueeze the join with alternation (pipes) makes sense then.  Or, if the only problem is readability, you could just use the /x modifier to allow whitespace and comments:
[RegEx Modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)
"/x tells the regular expression parser to ignore most whitespace that is neither backslashed nor within a bracketed character class. You can use this to break up your regular expression into (slightly) more readable parts. Also, the "#" character is treated as a metacharacter introducing a comment..."

Answer (score 1):

Perl Regex subpatterns can be joined together with pipes to make them alternating patterns.  To separate alternating patterns from the rest of the expression pattern, delimit them as a group.  If you don't want to capture what was matched by the group, make it a non-capturing group.

For example, alternation in a capturing group within a pattern:

`(move|jump|call) ([^ ]+)`

And alternation in a non-capturing group within a pattern:

`(?:move|jump|call) ([^ ]+)`

If your alternative patterns are complicated and you don't want them all on one line, you can use the /x modifier to separate them with whitespace.

[Perldoc PerlRe Modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) (scroll down to "Details on some modifiers")

> /x
>
> /x tells the regular expression parser to ignore most whitespace that
>   is neither backslashed nor within a bracketed character class. You can
>   use this to break up your regular expression into (slightly) more
>   readable parts. Also, the "#" character is treated as a metacharacter
>   introducing a comment that runs up to the pattern's closing delimiter,
>   or to the end of the current line if the pattern extends onto the next
>   line. Hence, this is very much like an ordinary Perl code comment.
>   (You can include the closing delimiter within the comment only if you
>   precede it with a backslash, so be careful!)
>
> Use of /x means that if you want real whitespace or "#" characters in
>   the pattern (outside a bracketed character class, which is unaffected
>   by /x), then you'll either have to escape them (using backslashes or
>   \Q...\E ) or encode them using octal, hex, or \N{} escapes. It is
>   ineffective to try to continue a comment onto the next line by
>   escaping the \n with a backslash or \Q.

And here's my example demonstrating that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = "jump 0xbdf3487";

if ($s =~ /^(

          move   # first complicated pattern

          |

          jump   # second complicated pattern

          |

          call   # third complicated pattern

    )\s([^\ ]+) /x) {   # Note I hade to escape the space
                        # with a backslash because of /x

    print "matched '$1' '$2'\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

`matched 'jump' '0xbdf3487'`